# How to Convert a Matrix into an Association?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, associations

I have a matrix like this one:

```
test = {{1, "a"}, {3, "b"}}
```

and I want to convert it into an association like this
`Association[ {1} → "a",{3} → "b" ]` for a classify method.

I have tried using `{ Most @ # -> Last @ #}` without success. Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `Association[Most[#] -> Last[#] & /@ test]`.

Comment: `AssociationThread @@ Transpose@test`

Comment: `KeyMap[List]@` `%[yode]`

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: So combining the answers by Kuba and yode reveals: `test // RightComposition[ Transpose, Apply[AssociationThread], KeyMap[List] ]` for readability. :)

Answer (score 9):

Here are a few ways, each returning `<| {1} -> "a", {3} -> "b" |>`:

```
Association[{#} -> #2 & @@@ test]

GroupBy[test, Most -> Last, First]

ReplacePart[test, {0 -> Association, {_, 0} -> ({#} -> #2 &)}]

test // Query[Association, Most@# -> Last@# &]

test // Query[GroupBy[Most -> Last], First]
```

Answer (score 7):

Collecting the comments as an answer for the reader.

This was my first thought:

```
AssociationThread @@ Transpose @ test
```

> `<|1 -> "a", 3 -> "b"|>`

But an undocumented but somewhat slower function also came to mind:

```
GeneralUtilities`AssociatePairs[test]
```

> `<|1 -> "a", 3 -> "b"|>`

#### Performance

```
testlist = RandomInteger[100, {1000000, 2}];
GeneralUtilities`AssociatePairs[testlist]; // AbsoluteTiming
AssociationThread @@ Transpose@testlist; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{1.0462, Null}`
>
> `{0.160241, Null}`

#### Lists as keys

If you want to use lists for keys, you can apply the `KeyMap` to the result as mentioned in [gwr's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116369/how-to-convert-a-matrix-into-an-association#comment315899_116369) and [Kuba's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116369/how-to-convert-a-matrix-into-an-association#comment315892_116369). Then you will get

> `<|{1} -> "a", {3} -> "b"|>`